# Defining alias works as expected in .bash_profile, but not in sourced script

Tags: bash

If I have the following line in .bash_profile:

```
alias j="ls -ltr"
```

Then I type `j` at the command prompt, the output is as expected.  But if I put the alias command in a separate file, and source it from .bash_profile:

```
source ./aliases
```

or

```
. ./aliases
```

Then type `j` at the command prompt, the output is:

```
's: invalid option -- '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

I have tried various ways of quoting and escaping.  I do not know why it is different when the alias command is sourced from a separate file.  The output of `uname -a` is:

```
Linux vbox4rhel 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 8 13:30:15 EST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I would like to know what is different when the alias command is in a separate file that is sourced.  Thanks.

Comment: The garbled error message indicates that your `aliases` file is in DOS/Windows format, which can cause all sorts of trouble. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see anything to click on to accept the answer, but that was the correct answer.

Comment: Check my edit, it will show you how to format code and/or commands in questions.